# Java solution for N boxes stacking problem. Do you think there can be a better algorithm?

Tags: java

Imagine you have N boxes. You are allowed to divide them into groups exactly once, at each step, over N attempts.

Input:  N representing the number of boxes

Output: each iteration will split the boxes into two groups Left and Right. Therefore, it will produce Left x Right as the score for that row until LEFT = 1 and RIGHT =1
The result will be the SUM of row scores

```
e.g. 

8
16  4  4
4   2  2  4
4   2  2  2  2
1   1  1   2  2  2
1   1  1   1   1  2  2
1   1  1   1   1   1   1  2
1   1  1   1   1   1   1   1  1
Result: 28
```

```
Tests

Input 7 will produce 21
Input 8 will produce 28
Input 9 will produce  ?
Input 10 will produce ?
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
package main;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    /**
     * Iterate through each line of input.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            long n = Long.parseLong(line);
            long result = getHeights(n);
            System.out.println(result);
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
   
    static long getHeights(long n){
        long result = 0;
        ArrayList<Long> heights = new ArrayList<>();
        long left, right;
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
            long item = heights.size()>0?heights.get(i):n;
            if (heights.size() > 0)
                heights.remove(i);
            if (item % 2 == 0) {
                long step = item / 2;
                left = step;
                right = step;
                heights.add(count, left);
                heights.add(count, right);
            } else {
                left = 1;
                right =  item - 1L;
                heights.add(0, left);
                heights.add(i==0?1:i,right);
                count++;
            }

            if (right >= 1){
                result = (left * right) + result;
            }

            System.out.println(result + "   " + Arrays.toString(heights.toArray()));
        }
        System.out.println();
        return result;
    }
}
```